# How to fetch only a few table columns from Database through Hibernate and marshal using JAXB?

Tags: hibernate, rest, jaxb

I have an Employee table with fields empId, empName, Dept, DOJ, DoB, Sex, Qualification in my database and a lot of records.

I have service and Dao Classes and my EMP Java resource Class is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP")
@XmlRootElement(name = "EmpResource")
public class Employee{

    private String empId;
    private String empName;
    private String href; // this field doesn't exist in the database table.

    @XmlElement
    public String getEmpId(){
        return empId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getEmpName(){
        return empId;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getHref(){
        return "http://host/rest/v1/employees/" + empId;
    }

}
```

I am working to create a REST based url where the url http://host/rest/v1/employees with fetch all records with only EmpId, EmpName and href fields but when I try to run the application I get this error

> `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.vargo.EmpResource nor any of its super class is known to this context.`

Any help?

Regards,
Kicha

Comment: The following example may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

Answer (score 0):

well, seems like the problem is in the biding of the xml that contains the data (im not seeing that code) but make sure you are providing the right path in:

`JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("pathWhereYourGeneratedJaxbClassesAre");`

hope this to be helpful.